# How many fragments can I add to FragmentTransaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need help please:

How many fragments can I add to FragmentTransaction?

My app contains more than 50 fragments and I wish work with fragment manager for go trough them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As much as the device allows before running out of memory. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/MvQ_rctYq2I

Comment: Why on earth do you need 50 Fragments? That seems far too many. Why not use some abstraction for your "history" or whatever you need for your task.

Comment: I have a survey that contains over 200 questions and want to split into fragments and progressing to the end, I must also be able to go back. I want to work on a single entity and go replacing content.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a list view.